# I get error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import smtplib
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

        
def login():
    status = messagebox.askokcancel('Enter','Do you want to login ?')
    d = user.get()
    test =Label(gu1,text=d).pack()
    # if status ==0:
    #     pass
    # else:
    #     id = user.get()
    #     test1=Label(gu1,text=id).pack()
        # sys.exit()
gu1= Tk()
gu1.geometry("450x550")
gu1.title("Acoount")
text = Label(text='Enter to your account ').pack(ipady=20)
 
user=Entry().pack()
password=Entry().pack()

Button(gu1,text="Login",fg='red',command = login).pack()
gu1.mainloop()
```

I get this error I did the following other people but they can do it unless me
anyone can help me or explain or solve my problem pls help me I want your suggestion

Comment: After you do `from tkinter import *` you don't need to import specific names.

Comment: @Barmar - Actually, those in particular are independent modules within the `tkinter` package that do need to be imported separately.

Comment: Can we not [edit the question into a different one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision). Ask a new question instead.

Comment: As a hint (to save you from asking it) your edited question is a silly typo `newWinow` instead of `newWindow`

Answer (score 0):

`pack()` returns None and that is what you assign to `user` and `password`. Separate your code on 2 lines. e.g.

```
user =  Entry()
user.pack()
```

Also note that it's better to work with [control variables](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/control-variables.html), e.g. `StringVar` to handle the value in your Entry widget. The link is to somewhat outdated resource, but still one of the best on Tkinter, in my opinion.

Comment: oh i got it  i can solve this thank u so much